# eliminate the last line of the shell script output

Tags: shell

my shell script output is below

```
43113 22/Mar/2017:00
37745 22/Mar/2017:01
31465 22/Mar/2017:02
24398 22/Mar/2017:03
22416 22/Mar/2017:04
17276 22/Mar/2017:05
```

I want to eliminate and send the remaining output to a mail ID, further this output lines are of hourly basis and i wanted to eliminate the current hour i.e the last line of the output and display the below

```
43113 22/Mar/2017:00
37745 22/Mar/2017:01
31465 22/Mar/2017:02
24398 22/Mar/2017:03
22416 22/Mar/2017:04
```

Comment: Pipe the output to [`head -n -1`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/head) and it prints all but the last `1` line of the input.

Comment: Use: `command | sed '$d'`